# Updated to Xcode8, .xib interfaces files are strange

Tags: ios, xcode

Not sure exactly what is going on, but when I open my .xib files in the interface, I only see blue outlines instead of the actual content.  I am also having "An internal error occurred. Editing functionality may be limited".  This happens for all my .xib files and storyboard files, and only happened after I migrated my code from Swift 2 to Swift 3.

What is the workaround?

[image]

Comment: Delete your project from the derived data folder.

Comment: Select/Change the size classes/screen size given at the bottom of your xib/Storyboard. It may work.

Comment: Deleting project from derived data folder was solution.  Thank you